# App crashes on iOS 8.1.3, can't reproduce issue

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, swift, crash

I recently submitted an app(spritekit game made using swift)to the app store, and it was rejected because a bug was found in it. Apple's exact response was:

**We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 8.1.3 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.
Specifically, the app loads to a blank display. Please refer to the attached screenshot for more information.**

I was sent a blank screenshot (that was grey), but that was of no help. I cannot reproduce the issue as the app runs fine on my iPad (8.1.3). Does anyone know what this can be? I tested the same build that was sent to apple.

Here's my view controller code:

```
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene:SKScene = GameScene()

        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
        scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size

        skView.presentScene(scene)

}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
    } else {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Here's some code from the first scene of the game(didMoveToView):

```
    authenticateLocalPlayer()

    //add background
    self.addChild(backgroundpic)

    //retrieve ad
    //loadAds()

    //get high score
    var accessPlayScene = PlayScene()
    var gameSceneHighScore = accessPlayScene.returnHighScore()
    //set background color
    backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()

    //add leaderboardbutton
    leaderBoardButton.position = CGPointMake((CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)), ((-1) * self.frame.size.height*0.27))
    self.addChild(leaderBoardButton)

    //add play button
    self.tutorialButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)*(-0.05))
    self.addChild(self.tutorialButton)

    //add high score label
    gameSceneHighScoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.redColor()
    gameSceneHighScoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), (CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)*0.75))
    gameSceneHighScoreLabel.text = "High Score: " + String(gameSceneHighScore)
    self.addChild(gameSceneHighScoreLabel)

    //add intro text
    self.appName.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),(CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)*0.90))
    self.addChild(appName)

    //add tutorial button
    PLAYBUTTON.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)*0.45)
    self.addChild(PLAYBUTTON)
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: "running iOS 8.1.3 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks" Does this mean that you do some sort of networking when your app launches? If so, that's the problem.

Comment: The app uses iAd, but that seems to work fine. Even when I took iAd out of the app and resubmitted, I received the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted app review and they essentially said the app runs fine on iPad and iPhone. I have no idea why or how they initially had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Only a guess: Does the loading of the view depend on the uikeyboard being visible at all?  Apple tests using the simulator, and if they do not have the software keyboard enabled, then that might not trigger the your views to show.  On an actual device, this is never a problem.

Comment: The view does initially load a keyboard in order to  allow the user to sign into Game Center, so you may be onto something but the app runs fine in my simulator. The problem lies in 1. not knowing what the problem is and 2. not being able to reproduce the error. Assuming you are correct, how would i be able to fix this?

Comment: Command+K toggles the software keyboard on and off.  When you you want to type using your hardware keyboard, you disable the software keyboard, and it goes away on the simulated phone.  Now if you try running the app with the software keyboard disabled (and the hardware keyboard enabled), your view might not load correctly.  Apple tests with the software keyboard disabled, since it allows them to type in your app using the hardware keyboard.  Let me know if that causes the app to not load, and I'll tell you what to do with Apple.

Comment: I turned the software keyboard off and the app still ran fine in my iPad simulator.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized i was a bit incorrect.  Command+K toggles the software keyboard on and off (which in turn could affect how your view loads), but enabled the software keyboard does not necessarily disable your hardware keyboard.  The command for that is Command+Shift+K

Comment: Well, are there any other events that are triggering the subviews to be displayed?  My point is that this might not be a bug (like an exception/crash), but actually just might be a display issue.  Are your subviews hidden at first and then fade in at some point?

Comment: None of the views fade in or out. i'll post some viewController and gamescene code.

Comment: btw, i wouldn't put too much credence into it being an iPad that Apple mentioned.  If your app is universal, a lot of times they'll test on an iPad, and if they run into a bug, then they won't even bother with an iPhone.  So it might not be related it being an iPad at all.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app on simulator and cleaning before your run your app?  Maybe it's an issue when the app is installed for the first time?

Comment: I have deleted the app off of the simulator before and it still ran fine. I did not try cleaning anything though.

Comment: Delete the app, clean (command+shift+K in xcode) just in case, and then build

Comment: I deleted the app and cleaned in Xcode but nothing changed